# Accepted answer removed - Is it possible to find out why?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

The following (accepted) answer has just been removed: "java libraries to read barcodes from a pdf"

Is it possible to find out why? I know it wasn't for commercial reasons since I am not affiliated with any Java library.

Comment: Thanks! I should have done the search myself. How did you come up with the link?

Comment: Google still had it indexed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896663/java-libraries-to-read-barcodes-from-a-pdf) (10k+ only) was deleted because it is off-topic:

> - "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

It was a library request, and those attract spam over time.

In this case, because you have < 10k reputation, the only way you could have learned this is by asking here on Meta. If *just* your answer was deleted, it would be listed under the 'recently deleted answers' link you can find at the bottom of your Answers tab in your profile.

Comment: I just visited my deleted answers page, and there are answers in there for which the entire question was deleted. Do answers on deleted questions go there too, or does this mean my answer was deleted _then_ the entire question was deleted too?

Comment: No, answers for which the question was deleted are listed there, but you cannot view those answers when you click on the link (IIRC).

Comment: That is the case. That makes sense then, thank you.